# Pro-rate calculation in database query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgres database structure with sample data

```
 id | impressions | position
=============================
 1  | 123         | 5.15
 2  | 456         | 10.12
 3  | 789         | 0.15
```

What I need to do is to get the sum of all impressions and the pro-rate calculation *(impressions * position) / impressions* in one result row. I cannot use `AVG(position)`, because the impressions for each row must serve as weights in order to get adequate result.

I can easily do this with getting the whole result set and iterating over it, but in my particular case this cannot be done.

==================================

EXPECTED OUTPUT IS

```
array (

    [0] => sum(impressions) = (123 + 456 + 789) = 1368

    [1] => position = (123 * 5.15 + 456 * 10.12 + 789 * 0.15) / (123 + 456 + 789) = 3.922

)
```

Comment: I edited my question with the expected output. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

What's the expected output ? If you want to have an other column with the output of your query, you can do a `SUM` for the `impressions` column and then create a `COMPUTED` column in order to have your pro-rate calculation.(If I've understand your demand)

Answer (score 0):

Just implement what you describe:

```
select sum(impressions * position) / sum(impressions)
from t;
```